# How to read return when using stty -icanon

Tags: bash, stty

I have a loop after setting stty -icanon time 0 min 0 to prevent read from blocking.

It works okay except it cant read the enter/return key.

Is there any way to read the enter key in this mode, or any other way my code could be written ?

### Relevant Code

```
tput smcup
Draw
if [ -t 0 ]; then stty -icanon time 0 min 0; fi
count=0
keypress=''
while [ "$keypress" != "q" ]; do
        sleep 0.1
        (( count = count + 1 ))
        rows=$(tput lines)
        columns=$(tput cols)
        Draw
        read  keypress
        name=$name$keypress
        echo $name
        if [[ $oldcolumns != $columns || $oldrows != $rows ]];then
                Draw
                oldcolumns=$columns
                oldrows=$rows
        elif [[ $count -eq 1  ]]; then
#               Draw
                count=0
        fi
done

if [ -t 0 ]; then stty sane; fi
tput rmcup
#rm tail.tmp
echo "Thanks for using this script."
exit 0
```

Comment: I think the problem is that `read` will return nothing if it receives just a newline.

Comment: Thats what i was thinking, ive looked around and can only find [read] as a way of taking user input, do you know of any other functions or methods of reading key strokes ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with read by

- unsetting IFS
- not using any line delimiters
- reading exactly 1 char at a time

.

```
IFS= read -t 0.01 -d '' -n1 keypress
```

For example, here we enter <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>space</kbd>, then <kbd>return</kbd>:

```
$ IFS= read -t 0.01 -s -d '' -n1 keypress ; echo "\"$keypress\""
"a"
$ IFS= read -t 0.01 -s -d '' -n1 keypress ; echo "\"$keypress\""
" "
$ IFS= read -t 0.01 -s -d '' -n1 keypress ; echo "\"$keypress\""
"
"
$
```

<sub>I added the `-s` flag in the above examples to suppress echoed input to `read`, so it doesn't confuse what is output.  This is not necessary for the above to work.</sub>

#### Edit:

I hadn't appreciated that you effectively want non-blocking mode for your reads until I saw your comment.  This is harder.  The best I can figure out is to put a small (10msec) timeout in your read command.  This has the unfortunate effect of a 10msec delay in your event loop, which may or may not be acceptable.  For me, much smaller timeouts caused bash to behave badly, and a 0 timeout doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Hi  Thanks for the answer. Where in the code i posted would you place it ?  If i put it within the loop where the read currently is, then it blocks until i input something.

Comment: @Jidder Sorry I hadn't appreciated that you need a non-blocking read.  I made an edit which may or may not be useful to you.